# Playing audio with directshow from resource file

Tags: c++, audio, resources, directshow

i am currently writing a script mod for Grand Theft Auto IV using Scripthook C++.
I have been playing audio files by using this template: [Simple C++ MP3 Player Class](http://cppmp3player.codeplex.com/documentation)

My problem starts by attempting to use files from resource.
I have no idea how to load them.

Every time i tried to load sound from resource using my code, game crashed.
Already spend hours browsing google about how to play DirectShow audio from resource without any result.

Inside resource files:

```
(resource.h)  #define WAV_Sound            106
(resource.rc) WAV_Sound                    RCDATA                  "MySound.wav"
```

Loading files from HDD is working fine

```
Load(TEXT("MySound.wav"));
```

But game crashes when i try one of this:

```
// Load from resource #1
    LPCWSTR file = MAKEINTRESOURCE(WAV_Sound);
    Load(file);

// Load from resource #2
    Load((LPCWSTR) WAV_Sound);
```

Hope someone can help me out, thanks !

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but i still didn't manage how to get it to work. Thats what i managed to write, but can't hear any audio when i run my script ... 
'hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT("EMS MOD.asi"));
 hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(WAV_MV_ReportingForDuty), RT_RCDATA);
 hResLoad = LoadResource(hExe, hRes);
 Audio_Load((LPCWSTR) hResLoad);
 Audio_Play();'

Comment: `DirectShow` for playing from resource is possible but would be a dramatic overkill. If the file is small, the best would be to use LoadResource API and play through legacy `waveOutOpen` and friends (straightforwardly: convert the while file and then add it for playback as a single large buffer). There should be some tutorial for compressed audio as well, for starters http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recommended using DirectX Audio to provides multilayer interfaces for developing game, namely XAudio2, X3DAudio, XACT, ... etc, they are very powerful to process sound effect in 2d/3d game environment. Here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415737%28v=vs.85%29

Please download and install the DirectX software development kit, and find the 'XAudio2BasicSound' example to open wave file from file or in resource or in dll and playback with IXAudio2 interface, it was very simple example but next step you can add sound effect to your game.